# opening and closing tabControl with label click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am curious if there is an easier way to open a tabControl with a single click open and single click hide.

The code I am using is as follows

```
private void lblCustomize_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tabcontrol1.Show();
}
```

And to hide the tabControl I use

```
private void lblCustomize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tabControl1.Hide();
}
```

This works fine the way I have it. I am just curious how I would have it as a single click both ways for showing and hiding.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the event like this in your form onLoad:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Click += Label1_Click;
}

private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.Visible) 
    { 
        tabControl1.Hide(); 
    } else 
    {
        tabControl1.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I did not think of that. Thanks @Anthony Guertin its been a long 15 hour day. So thanks, and I will do it first thing in the morning. It's 9:00 pm here and 4:30am comes earlier than I want it too. Thanks guys.

Comment: I feel ya man, I get goo brain after 5:00pm. There are a couple of other ways you can do it as well if you'd like to discuss it some more tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You need an if in your single click method:

```
private void lblCustomize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(tabControl1.IsVisible){
        tabControl1.Hide();
    }
    else{
        tabControl1.Show();
    }
}
```

This checks to see if your tab control is/isn't already hidden and flips it accordingly.